# Getting invalid_grant: authentication failure

Tags: ruby, salesforce, restforce

I try to connect to salesforce via restforce gem. I use next:

```
client = Restforce.new(username: 'user@name.com',
                           password: 'my_password',
                           client_id: 'Consumer_Key',
                           client_secret: 'Consumer_Secret',
                           security_token: 'security_token',
                           api_version: '38.0',
                           grant_type: 'password',
                           ssl: {version: 'TLSv1'})
contacts = client.query("select ID__c from Contacts where Name = 'Lorem Ipsum'")
puts contacts.first
```

When I try to execute it I'm getting next error:
`'authenticate!': invalid_grant: authentication failure (Restforce::AuthenticationError)`

In salesforce app I set:

- Permitted Users: *All users may self-authorize*.
- IP Relaxation: *Relax IP restrictions*.

Checked with enabled and disabled OAuth.

Also I've tried with simple configuration:

```
client = Restforce.new(username: 'user@name.com',
                       password: 'my_password',
                       client_id: 'Consumer_Key',
                       client_secret: 'Consumer_Secret',
                       api_version: '38.0',)
```

But got the same error

Valid credentials for salesforce were specified.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was? I have got the same problem.

Comment: I identified the issue on my side : it was IP Relation settings issue.

Comment: Problem was on Salesforce side. App was configured incorrectly.